# Three js embed html

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Hy!
I'm working with three js(webgl). I was trying to embed html webpage, but somehow it don't wants to work.
Tutorials that I was checking:
http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/
http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html

The stemkoski one was working with three js v58, also v60. But it don't realy wants to work using v68(newest version). I don't get any error message, just a black screen where the website should be.

Also I'm able to do something similiar like http://threejs.org/examples/#css3d_youtube .

My question is is there a workaround, or "hot fix" for this problem because I'm out of ideas.

Thanks for your answers.

***---UPDATE---***

Then let's say I'm using this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CSS3D (Three.js)</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel=stylesheet href="css/base.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<script src="js/Three58.js"></script>
<script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
<script src="js/Stats.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.KeyboardState.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.FullScreen.js"></script>
<script src="js/THREEx.WindowResize.js"></script>

<!-- new for this example -->
<script src="js/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>

<!-- jQuery code to display an information button and box when clicked. -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel=stylesheet href="css/info.css"/>
<script src="js/info.js"></script>
<div id="infoButton"></div>
<div id="infoBox" title="Demo Information">
This three.js demo is part of a collection at
<a href="http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/">http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/</a>
</div>
<!-- ------------------------------------------------------------ -->

<div id="ThreeJS" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:0px"></div>
<script>
/*
    Three.js "tutorials by example"
    Author: Lee Stemkoski
    Date: July 2013 (three.js v58)

    This demo is based on the work of Jerome Etienne:
    http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/

 */

// MAIN

// standard global variables
var container, scene, camera, renderer, controls, stats;
var keyboard = new THREEx.KeyboardState();
var clock = new THREE.Clock();
// custom global variables
var rendererCSS;

init();
animate();

// FUNCTIONS        
function init() 
{
    // SCENE
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    // CAMERA
    var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth, SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 45, ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, NEAR = 0.1, FAR = 20000;
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.set(0,150,400);
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);  
    // RENDERER
    if ( Detector.webgl )
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
    else
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer(); 
    renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    container = document.getElementById( 'ThreeJS' );
    container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
    // EVENTS
    THREEx.WindowResize(renderer, camera);
    THREEx.FullScreen.bindKey({ charCode : 'm'.charCodeAt(0) });
    // CONTROLS
    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
    // STATS
    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    stats.domElement.style.bottom = '0px';
    stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
    container.appendChild( stats.domElement );
    // LIGHT
    var light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
    light.position.set(0,250,0);
    scene.add(light);
    // FLOOR
    var floorTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'images/checkerboard.jpg' );
    floorTexture.wrapS = floorTexture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; 
    floorTexture.repeat.set( 10, 10 );
    var floorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: floorTexture, side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
    var floorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1000, 1000, 10, 10);
    var floor = new THREE.Mesh(floorGeometry, floorMaterial);
    floor.position.y = -0.5;
    floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
    scene.add(floor);

    ////////////
    // CUSTOM //
    ////////////

    var planeMaterial   = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, opacity: 0.1, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    var planeWidth = 360;
    var planeHeight = 120;
    var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( planeWidth, planeHeight );
    var planeMesh= new THREE.Mesh( planeGeometry, planeMaterial );
    planeMesh.position.y += planeHeight/2;
    // add it to the standard (WebGL) scene
    scene.add(planeMesh);

    // create a new scene to hold CSS
    cssScene = new THREE.Scene();
    // create the iframe to contain webpage
    var element = document.createElement('iframe')
    // webpage to be loaded into iframe
    element.src = "index.html";
    // width of iframe in pixels
    var elementWidth = 1024;
    // force iframe to have same relative dimensions as planeGeometry
    var aspectRatio = planeHeight / planeWidth;
    var elementHeight = elementWidth * aspectRatio;
    element.style.width  = elementWidth + "px";
    element.style.height = elementHeight + "px";

    // create a CSS3DObject to display element
    var cssObject = new THREE.CSS3DObject( element );
    // synchronize cssObject position/rotation with planeMesh position/rotation 
    cssObject.position = planeMesh.position;
    cssObject.rotation = planeMesh.rotation;
    // resize cssObject to same size as planeMesh (plus a border)
    var percentBorder = 0.05;
    cssObject.scale.x /= (1 + percentBorder) * (elementWidth / planeWidth);
    cssObject.scale.y /= (1 + percentBorder) * (elementWidth / planeWidth);
    cssScene.add(cssObject);

    // create a renderer for CSS
    rendererCSS = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
    rendererCSS.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    rendererCSS.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    rendererCSS.domElement.style.top      = 0;
    rendererCSS.domElement.style.margin   = 0;
    rendererCSS.domElement.style.padding  = 0;
    document.body.appendChild( rendererCSS.domElement );
    // when window resizes, also resize this renderer
    THREEx.WindowResize(rendererCSS, camera);

    renderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    renderer.domElement.style.top      = 0;
    // make sure original renderer appears on top of CSS renderer
    renderer.domElement.style.zIndex   = 1;
    rendererCSS.domElement.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

}

function animate() 
{
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();       
    update();
}

function update()
{
    if ( keyboard.pressed("z") ) 
    { 
        // do something
    }

    controls.update();
    stats.update();
}

function render() 
{
    // remember to call both renderers!
    rendererCSS.render( cssScene, camera );
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As I mentioned above, this is the code from  http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/CSS3D.html, and he made his code from another tutorial: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/   this one.

The problem is, theese are working on three js r58-r60(Let's say theese are old codes). I want to do the same thing with three js r68(the newest version). But somehow, when I launch the same code on r68 that screen goes black instead of showing a html page. This is a known bug, you can check it  http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2013/04/30/closing-the-gap-between-html-and-webgl/ here:

> Hi Jerome, thanks for your interest. Here are a couple of jsfiddles
>   copied from stemkoski's github showing the results of Three r58 and
>   r68. Observe that the only difference between the samples is the
>   library in use: Threejs 58 (working) - http://jsfiddle.net/jL48v/2/
>   Threejs 68 (broken) - http://jsfiddle.net/jL48v/3/
>
> I've tried several approaches to get this technique working in r68,
>   but without much luck so far.
>
> Just realized that I messed up the dependency load order.  Here's a
>   "fixed" broken version of r68 - http://jsfiddle.net/jL48v/4/

But he/she forgot to write the solution. and the v4 not working either.

Comment: Sorry your question is not very clear. Do you want to mix html and webgl? Then the first example is the way to go but you have to make it work for the three.js release you are working on. Post code and problem.

Comment: Solved it! I'll "commit" the result tomorrow, now time to sleep ^^.